# How to integrate a banner(picture) with text on the banner

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a scalable banner(picture) with text in it.

Thats what I have tried:

1)

```
width: 100%;
height:auto;
```

=> Disadvantage: You can not put other elements into an img element.

2)

```
background: url("../img/banner.jpg") no-repeat center center;
width: 1920px;
height: 400px;
```

=> Disadvantage: Image does not scale

3)

```
background: url("../img/bannerjpg") no-repeat center center;
width: 100%;
height: 400px;

=> Disadvantage: Image does not scale
```

4)

```
background: url("../img/banner.jpg") no-repeat center center;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

=> Disadvantage: Picture disappears

I hope you understand my question. Is there a professional solution to solve my problem?
It does not necessarily have to be a CSS solution. JavaScript is also possible.

Comment: Is the text an overlay or directly below the image. Can you do a mock up in paint

Comment: It is an overlay. The text is in the center of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, if you are using image as `background`, try `background-size: cover`. It will scale the image to full width and height of the container for you, keeping the ratio, but will re-position the image a little bit.

Another option is using `<img>` and `object-fit` to fit it inside the parent element. To put text on top of it, you can set the parent element position to `relative` and the `text` element position to `absolute`.

Something like:

```
<div class="parent"> <!-- this element should have position relative ->
   <img /> <!-- image with height, width equal to parent and object fit to scale -->
   <p>[TEXT]</p> <!-- text element with position absolute and proper z-index so it stay on top of the image -->
</div>
```

More on `background-size`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size.

And `object-fit`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: I've tried that, but it didn't work. When I resize the browser window, then the text is out of the image.    https://jsfiddle.net/dpk3db7s/9/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dpk3db7s/12/ I gave you an example here, basically, how to position your element with css is much more broader topic.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the image as the element that will set the banner size. If you use it as background image you'll have to set the height of the **div.banner**, otherwise it's height will be the height of the text only.

So I use the scalable image and I wrap the text on **div.banner_text** and I use *position:absolute* so every text or other html element that I put on it will be placed above the image.

HTML

```
<div class="banner">
    <img src="banner.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="banner_text">
        <h1>Bla bla bla</h1>
        <p>bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.banner {
    position: relative;
}

.banner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

.banner_text {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px; /* or whatever you want */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0; /* for banners like that I like to position the text from the bottom, but it's up to you */
    z-index: 10;
}
```